# Adding PackageReference for package fails with 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: authentication, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, dotnet-cli

I am trying to install a third-party NuGet package (e.g. StyleCop) into a project. The project also has packages that are installed from our own private NuGet feed. When trying to install the package, we receive a 401 error like this.

```
MyProject> dotnet add .\MyProject.csproj package StyleCop
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6A51.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'StyleCop' into project '.\MyProject.csproj'.
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/stylecop/index.json
info :   GET https://mediavaletsc.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/c559332f-5d8d-4d3f-8fc2-6e06125775fa/nuget/v3/registrations2-semver2/stylecop/index.json
info :   Unauthorized https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/nuget/v3/registrations2-semver2/stylecop/index.json 680ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Oddly enough, running `dotnet restore` works just fine, even after doing a `git clean -xfd`. How can we configure `dotnet` and/or `nuget` to accept the installation of `StyleCop` or any other public package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We needed to re-authenticate with Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) because the API key had expired and/or been revoked.

The reason `dotnet restore` still worked, but `dotnet add ... package ...` failed, was because the former used the local cache, whereas the latter hit the server. Restore also stopped working after we ran `nuget locals all -clear`.

To re-authenticate with did the following.

```
nuget sources remove -name $sourceName | Out-Null;
nuget sources add -name $sourceName -source $sourcePath -username $username -password $apiKey
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.

Comment: Done. Thx for the feedback @EdwardHan-MSFT.